# IF weekday is equal to days off - excel

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, excel-formula, hour

I am attempting to get if the day off is the same day of the row to do an equation, I have Off days in G & H 4.  Now in the Double row I am trying to get if its the second day off (H4) then calculate it as Double time, but only if a total of 48 hours have been worked for the week.  If first day off calculate it as Overtime but only if total hours is over 40 hours.

The formula would go into straight, overtime and double rows. I am struggling really bad trying to figure this out and have put a lot of time into it.

this is what I have so far for the double row

```
=IF(AND(N12="Yes",J14>=48),(F10-F7+(F10<F7)-(F9-F8))*24,0)
```

I was thinking something like

```
=IF(DATE OF ROW= H4,IF(AND(N12="Yes",J14>=48),(F10-F7+(F10<F7)-(F9-F8))*24,0))
```

but have no idea how to implement it.
I hope that makes sense.

Here's a screenshot for a little better understanding
[image: Example]

Comment: What if the total is 42? How much overtime should the person now get?

Comment: Anything over 40 is 1.5, anything over 48 and on the 7th day is 2x

Comment: So it isn't just "calculate double if the total is over 40", it is "calculate double of the part over 40". You have written your question as though there is a predicate to apply but instead you need to do a more complex calculation.

Comment: Our days off our flexed so like I have tues/weds off someone else could have weds/Thur

Comment: Is it possible to work 9 hours on tuesday and 9 on wednesday? If so, then how would you calculate this (forget the excel spreadsheet and how you would have to do it there, just your opinion on what the correct value should be and why)

Comment: And that's where I'm lost, it's been confusing me for a few days. We can work as many hours (up to 12) as we wish on off days, so I could do 8 tuesday to put me at 48 if I worked only my scheduled 8 hours all week.  Then work 4 on weds and have only 4 hours of double time.

Comment: And if you worked 10 hours on tuesday and 4 on wednesday I assume you should get 6 hours overtime?

Comment: 10 would go toward the scheduled 40 as OT, and the 4 would be double time since I would have had over 48 on my 7th day

Comment: Yes, but the last 2 hours of those 10 would already be over 40, if the first 8 of those 10 brought you to 40, and then the next 2 was over, should you get overtime for those 2 as well?

Comment: Anything over 8 is 1.5, anything over 40 is 1.5, anything over 48 on the 7th working day is double, you only get the double if you worked everyday prior.  It's a very confusing system but I've grown accustomed to it lol

Comment: It isn't that confusing to me, which is why I bring up these questions. I work on a product that this kind of calculation would be the simplest one to do. In any case, come up with a lot of test cases to ensure your formulas become correct, that's the best advice I can give.

Comment: Yes correct say I miss a day, and worked 10 on Tuesday the 8 would be regular and 2 of it would be 1.5

Comment: OK, and is there any way to reach those 40 hours without working those two days? If so, would you then get overtime as well?

Comment: If you worked your scheduled 8 hours 5 days yes, but anything over 8 hours even 1 minute is OT and you can stay after or come in early 4 hours

Comment: This type of calculation is going to create **very** complex formulas for you if you can have any combination of days off, and you need to attribute the overtime to those days and not just "the last day(s) you worked this week". I'm not saying it can't be done, but it's going to be very hard to get right.

Comment: You might be able to formulate a set of formulas on a separate tab that first sets up the days in the order you want them to apply, which would mean 5 days first that **aren't days off**, followed by the two days off. And then getting the time over from the respective days, because now you have things "in order".

Comment: You lost me at you might lol

Comment: Yes, I stand by my earlier assessment that this is going to be a very complex task to complete in Excel. A normal programming language where you have collections of data and can easily manipulate these collections would be far better suited.

Comment: To capture the date element I would suggest using an actual date for the day off and just use custom formatting to make it display `"dddd"`. You can then assess the date in row 6 with `WEEKDAY()` in the if statement.

Comment: Not at the PC right now, but something like if(weekday = cell1 or cell2, this, that)?

Comment: It converts the date to an integer that represents the weekday so it would be `IF(WEEKDAY(Date1)=WEEKDAY(Date2),this,that)`

Comment: good tip, ill play with it a little see what I can do =)

Comment: You had clearly state your need in the question, IMHO, I see that your case are quite straightforward...  Any luck so far? | If you had solve it, appreciate if you can share the solution. ( :

Comment: " If first day off calculate it as Overtime if total hours is over 40 hours. " <--- can you share the formula for this ? @ C12:I12  |  would like to know the "40 hours" calculation

Comment: Is this your intended solution? --> `=IF( AND(<DATE OF ROW> = H4, N12 = "Yes", J14 >= 48 ), ((F10-F7)-(F9-F8))*24, 0 )`